molecular electron isodensity surfaces, using latex
Atomic orbitals are currently visualized in latex using spherical surfaces.
Formulae for this can be found at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/376028984_Visualizing_atomic_orbitals_of_an_electron_by_Latex.
For example, in tikz:
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\Vt}{30}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110+\Vt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
            fill opacity=.5]
                \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
                \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
                {sqrt(7)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(5*(cos(\tdplottheta))^3-3*cos(\tdplottheta))}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%

                \draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle({sqrt(110)/(4*sqrt(pi))});
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110-\Vt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
            fill opacity=.5]
                \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
                \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
                {sqrt(105)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(sin(\tdplottheta))^2*cos(\tdplottheta)*sin(2*\tdplotphi)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%

                \draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] 
                (0,0) circle({sqrt(110)/(4*sqrt(pi))});
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110-\Vt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
            fill opacity=.5]
                \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
                \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
                {sqrt(15)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(sin(\tdplottheta))^2*cos(2*\tdplotphi)}
                {black}{\tdplotphi}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%

                \draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] 
                (0,0) circle({sqrt(110)/(4*sqrt(pi))});
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110+\Vt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
            fill opacity=.5]
                \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
                \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
                {sqrt(35)/(4*sqrt(2*pi))*(sin(\tdplottheta))^3*cos(3*\tdplotphi)}
                {black}{\tdplotphi}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
                {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
                -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%

                \draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] 
                (0,0) circle({sqrt(110)/(4*sqrt(pi))});
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


And also one in Asymptote for fun:
unitsize(1cm);

import three;
import graph3;

triple sphere(pair uv) {
    return (
        cos(uv.y)*cos(uv.x) * sqrt(105)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(sin(uv.x))^2*cos(uv.x)*sin(2*uv.y)
        ,cos(uv.y)*sin(uv.x) * sqrt(105)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(sin(uv.x))^2*cos(uv.x)*sin(2*uv.y)
        ,sin(uv.y) * sqrt(105)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(sin(uv.x))^2*cos(uv.x)*sin(2*uv.y)
    );
}

draw(
    surface(
        sphere
        ,(0,-pi/2)
        ,(2pi,pi/2)
        ,Spline
    )
    ,blue+opacity(0.5)
);


The problem:
While this is all fine and dandy for individual atoms, the electron isodensity surfaces of molecules on the other hand cannot be done spherically. For a simple instance, take water's electron density: [Credit: https://peverati.github.io/pchem2/Poly.html]

Or even more complicated surfaces: [Credit: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/MEP-surface-isodensity-0002-au-of-compound-1-The-values-are-selected-points-of_fig2_350211962]

I want to know if anyone has done any work in modelling these in latex? I think it would be  pretty cool to achieve. How does one go about making these?

Why not stick with specialist software here? Getting this right is quite hard

@JosephWright Do you have any suggestions? I'm interested in learning how such software works. I think this stuff is pretty cool. Pardon me if its not entirely insightful to do this in latex. Do you have any other insights?

Hm, 1) you may be able to replicate a given drawing, while computing those MEP surfaces will require very powerful computers. 2) With Heisenberg in mind it looks to me someone broke quantum mechanics here. Remember, that any real measurement (observation) changes the quantum menchanical systems state. You simply can't trick those into our (limited) macroscopic views. So: what's the practical value beyond "cool"? 3) What would you do with such a "cool result"? // From ref. 31: https://gaussian.com/

@MS-SPO I just remember learning this stuff in chemistry and thinking it was interesting. I didn't consider those quantum mechanical properties, though this surface is supposed to represent a probability density. And to answer your question about what I would do with such a result - the most obvious answer is visualize electron densities. I also think that in making it that it would really help me learn the requisite math for making the softwares that Joseph Wright mentioned.

Good reasons to rethink more than twice. And no, they don’t show probDens. Whatever they did doesn’t seem to include measurements, i.e. their effect. As a rule of thumb, what looks nice can still be wrong or useless wrt to the real world. See you

@MS-SPO They don't? I guess its possible I'm remembering the concept wrong. could you post a link to a real probability density surface?

Well, kcal/mol is Energy. What they mention in their paper is electrostatic potential. Just follow the link you posted to download the pdf. The link from my comment points to the program they cited.

@MS-SPO Interesting, I will do some more research tomorrow based on this information
